# Kotlin Code Style with parameters come in multiple lines rather than one line

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, intellij-idea

This is My Code Style (Before Reset)

```
CommUtil.showCAlertDialog(
            act = this,
            msg = getString(R.string.network_error_app_fake_msg),
            dialogFinishType = DialogFinishType.APP_PROCESS_KILL)
        return
```

But When I Reset My Computer And Download Android Studio
Set My Code Style Like this

```
CommUtil.showCAlertDialog(act = this, msg = getString(R.string.network_error_app_fake_msg), dialogFinishType = DialogFinishType.APP_PROCESS_KILL)
        return
```

What options should I set to return to the previous code style?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Settings -> Editor -> Code Sytle -> Kotlin -> Wrapping and Braces -> Function Call Arguments

Set it to "*Chop down if long*" or "*Wrap always*".